# What happens to python thread object, when the status of that object reached closed state?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, daemon, gevent

I am working on a python multithreading project.
The intent of the app/Project/Daemon was to do a process continuously  for 24/7 with difference parameters are input.
Multiple threads are created and at every instance.
Each thread will trigger a python grequests async process

My question's:

1. Even thought the thread reaches close state, still the process of the    particular PID's are available in the linux process management list.
2. In this case, what should i do to?
3. Whether these process do any malfunctions for my program.

Can any one please give me an idea regarding how i should progress?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [terminate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) the process created in the thread, before the thread is destroyed.

If the number of processes keeps on increasing, you may not have any memory left to create further new processes.

Comment: Hey Rayu.. As per my understanding from other tutorial.. there are no such API's for terminating a thread. Is there any way to implement the terminate the process? if at all not whether i should switch to multiprocessing are what?

Comment: You can find the URL for more info about terminating a process in my answer. (read "terminate").
If you are not using multiprocessing currently, you can find the PID of the process that you want to kill and use os.system("kill <PID>") to kill the process.

Comment: thanks.. I implemented the termination method and  its done... as of now my application is not troubling me in terms of memory or even thread process..